# Как поймать и обработать событие изменения содержимого поля TextField?

Tags: java, javafx, gui, fxml

Есть проект JavaFX. Интерфейс описан в FXML-файле, содержащем объект TextField:

```
<TextField fx:id="field" layoutX="95.0" layoutY="40.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="35.0" />
```

Необходимо обрабатывать событие изменения текста в поле.
Видел, как это делается, если TextField был создан в коде java, но как это сделать, когда он описан в FXML - непонятно.
Атрибут "onInputMethodTextChanged" в тэг TextField добавлял:

```
onInputMethodTextChanged="#controller_method_name"
```

Но, почему-то, метод при вводе текста в поле не вызывается (ошибок при этом нет).
Хотелось бы сделать это, по возможности, через какое-то указание метода-обработчика в самом FXML сразу (как с "onInputMethodTextChanged" пытался).

Comment: попробуйте использовать один из методов: onKeyPressed, onKeyReleased, onKeyTyped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По-видимому, то, что вы желаете, в java-коде контроллера выглядело бы как:

```
field.textProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue)->{...});
```

**Для JavaFX 8+ :**

Специально для Вашего случая (для обработчика `ChangeListener` свойств)
в JavaFX 8 внесли изменения, которые позволяют писать так:

```
<TextField onTextChange="#method" />
```

При этом в контроллере метод должен иметь такую сигнатуру:

```
public void method(ObservableValue observable, String oldValue, String newValue) {
    System.out.println("textonchange2(): "+oldValue+" -> "+newValue);
}
```

Ссылка на документацию:

[JavaFX 8. Introduction to FXML: Special handlers for collections and properties](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#collections_and_property_handlers)

---

**Ниже написанное верно для JavaFX 2.*:**

*(Оставляю в качестве примера, как пользоваться javascript в FXML)*

К сожалению, у стандартного `TextField` нет свойства что-бы сделать что-то наподобие `<TextField onTextChange="#..."/>`.

Также тип свойства `textProperty` — это `TextProperty`, и в этом классе тоже нет подходящего JavaFX-свойства (чтобы попробовать что-нибудь вроде `<TextField><text onChange="#..."/></TextField>`).

Остается либо реализовать свой класс-наследник `TextField`, в котором реализовать нужную функциональность,
либо использовать какой-либо другой обходной путь.

Из обходных путей наименее сложным, на мой взгляд, является использование встроенного javascript-движка Nashorn:

`// changetext.fxml:`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<?language javascript?>

<VBox xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx"
            xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml"
            fx:controller="changetext.ChangetextController"
            prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0">
    <TextField fx:id="myTextField" text="Привет!"/>
    <fx:script>
        myTextField.textProperty()["addListener(javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener)"](
            function(observable, oldValue, newValue){
                print('observable: ' + observable);
                print(' oldValue: ' + oldValue);
                print(' newValue: ' + newValue);
                controller.js2controller(observable, oldValue, newValue);
            });
    </fx:script>
</VBox>
```

Для этого примера важно, что скрипт находится после элемента — в этом случае объект `myTextField` уже создан `FXMLLoader`'ом.

Также стоит обратить внимание на указание сигнатуры при вызове метода `addListener()`, т.к. у него есть еще один перегруженный вариант с `InvalidationListener`.

Вызов Java-методов контроллера из javascript осуществляется через объект `controller`, который добавляется в глобальное пространство имен javascript `FXMLLoader`'ом при разборе атрибута `fx:controller`.

Сопутствующие файлы контроллера и приложения:

`// ChangetextController.java:`

```
package changetext;

import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;

public class ChangetextController {

    public TextField myTextField;

    public void js2controller(ObservableValue observable, String oldValue, String newValue) {
        System.out.println("js2controller(): " + oldValue + " -> " + newValue);
    }
}
```

`// ChangeTextMain.java:`

```
package changetext;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class ChangeTextMain  extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("changetext.fxml"));
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```