# javaFx TextField change value event

Tags: javafx, события

Как установить слушатель на изменения значения `textfield` и передать в него ссылку на `label`, чтобы новое значение отображалось в этом самом `label`?

Comment: [Вот](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/809451/213646) + код наподобие `label.setText( newValue );`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Такие варианты:

1. В обработчике изменения свойства `text` (см. полный пример ниже):

   ```
       textField.textProperty().addListener(
           (observable, oldValue, newValue) -> label.setText(newValue));
   ```
2. Через одностороннюю привязку свойств `text`:

   ```
       label.textProperty().bind(textField.textProperty());
   ```
3. В FXML, используя выражение (это тоже односторонняя привязка):

   ```
       <Label text="${textfield1.text}"/>
       <TextField fx:id="textfield1" />
   ```
4. Также в FXML [можно](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/809451/291565) (как подсказывает [Andrey M](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/213646/andrey-m)) использовать

   ```
       <TextField onTextChange="#method" />
   ```

   и соответствующий метод в классе контроллера. Единственное - на данный момент в Intellij Idea `onTextChange` будет отмечен ошибочным, так как такой способ еще не реализован в этой IDE (https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-184839).
5. [В том же ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/809451/291565) показано, как можно извратиться и то, что обычно делается в контроллере на java, сделать через javascript в FXML.

---

Полный пример для 1 (ссылка на label в обработчик передается через замыкание):

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class MainLabelFromTextField extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {

        Label label = new Label();
        TextField textField = new TextField();

        textField.textProperty().addListener(
            (observable, oldValue, newValue) -> label.setText(newValue));

        Parent root = new VBox(label, textField);
        stage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        stage.show();
    }
}
```